# Make rsync honor directory setuid

Tags: rsync

I have a destination dir with id bit set, i.e. -rwxrws---
If I mkdir within this dir, it creates new dirs with the dir bit set. But when I rsync into it, rsync creates new dirs without the dir bit set. I have specified `--no-owner --no-group --no-perms`, but doesn't help.